# Setting up Python 2.7 to work in both QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, pyqgis, arcgis-10.1, installation, python-2.7

I have both ArcGIS 10.1 and QGIS 1.8 installed and both include Python 2.7 in slightly different setups and in different folders (c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\ and c:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27).

It is only ArcGIS Desktop which include python.exe, while it is really QGIS I would like to start experimenting with for some scripting, but preferably just running my scripts from the command console.

How do I do this?

I'm thinking of settings environment variables etc.

I am new to both QGIS and Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can do it with the standalone installed copy of QGIS I would highly recommend installing QGIS and QGIS-dev using the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) installer.  OSGeo is [easier](http://nathanw.net/2013/05/03/installing-qgis-using-apt-on-windows-osgeo4w/) to update and lets you get the latest stuff.

That will install Python into `C:\OSGeo4W\app\Python27` and let you run Python from the OSGeo4W shell. `python.exe` lives in `C:\OSGeo4W\bin`.

I have some examples of QGIS stuff at https://github.com/NathanW2/pyqgis-playground

Use the following batch file as a bootstrap to your python file:

```
@ECHO OFF
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\python
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\
```

Comment: I have installed OSGeo4W instead of QGIS alone and have created this batch files:  SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27
Set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%
Set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
Set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\
%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\python test.py
The test test.py file only includes one line:</br>from qgis.core import *</br>But it fails with the error message that the DLL could not be loaded. Not saying which DLL it is.

Comment: Adding line breaks failed completely...

Comment: @UffeKousgaard see update

Comment: OK, thanks, I have gotten as far as opening a SHP file now. Just wondering, why all I get from this code is a "feature ID 0": http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html. no Error messages.

Comment: That needs to be updated for the new version.  Try this: https://gist.github.com/NathanW2/5525338

Comment: I got the while-version working by adding an additional (): while (provider.nextFeature(feat)): The for-loop I never got working. Another issue with the cookbook example is the function geom.vectorType(). It is now called geom.type().

Comment: Yeah it has been write for 1.8.  In the process of updating it.

Comment: this is a nice clear and concise answer for getting started with qgis python on Windows, but is doesn't address *"work in both QGIS and ArcGIS"* :)

Comment: ArcGIS ships with it's own version of Python mine lives in `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe`.  You can't really have them both setup at the same time else you get conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted [Using PyQGIS, ArcPy, NumPy, SciPy Together in Windows Command Prompt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157864) to this that may be helpful.  This is my take on how to utilize multiple python installations on the same computer.